# SQL Server union performance

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that does a union of 2 views on different databases. Individually, each query runs pretty quickly. 8 seconds for the top and about 22 for the bottom. When I run it with a join it runs past 2 minutes before I have to cancel it.

What could cause this? Here is the query:

```
select *
from v_flash_report
where type in ('Invoice')
union all 
select *
from [BC_BRT_Diamond].[dbo].v_Diamond_Flash
where type in ('Invoice','Cash')
```

The top one returns about 14k rows and the bottom returns 153k rows.

Is it fair to expect the entire thing to return in the same amount of time as the 2 individually added together?

This is running on SQL server 2019.

The databases themselves are restored backups from an old SQL server 2008 database. On the old database the query with the union runs in 47 seconds so I would expect the same on the new database. Is there a big difference in the way SQL Server may handle this type of query between the versions?

**EDIT** I should also mention that both v_flash_report and v_diamond_flash are views and not tables.

Comment: Copies of the query plans (with and without the `UNION ALL`) would be nice. The DDL of the views possibly too. Perhaps, however, you might be better off simply inserting the data separately into a temporary table and selecting from that? Especially if you're noticing that the 2 queries on their own are fast, but the `UNION ALL` is not.

Comment: The views themselves are quite complicated which is why I didn't include the DDL. I am considering using a temp table though. My main questions is why it takes so long with the union when individually they are fine.

Comment: 2019 has the ability to inline scalar functions which can cause problems. Other than that **guess**, the only way to know is to look at the execution plans.

Answer (score -2):

`SELECT *` avoid to use any indexes.

If the two queries has no identical rows, try `UNION ALL`

Comment: I am using union all. They are both views which name the columns in source queries so select * from the view shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: The OP *is* using `UNION ALL`. Also `SELECT *` won't cause the query to not use any indexes; if the table has a covering indexing one can still be used. The tables in the OP's question could be quite "thin", and have both a `CLUSTERED` index on their always ascending value, and an `INDEX` on `[type]` that contains in includes all the other columns. Of course, if they are wider, or the index on `[type]` doesn't at least `INCLUDE` every column in the table/view then a scan will be needed.